# Could fflush function increase file descriptors number in linux?

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, fflush

My application exited because it took up too many file descriptors . So I used gdb to debug  my program. I found file descriptors number increased  when I used fflush function.

for example:

```
//  before fflush  
// ll /proc/13593/fd/* | grep "send\.dat" | wc -l   
// 7 

     fflush(pFile);

//  after fflush  
// ll /proc/13593/fd/* | grep "send\.dat" | wc -l   
// 8
```

The process id is 13593. Variable pFile  points to file send.dat .

Could anybody tell me the reason ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to post a complete piece of code that demonstrates what you see.

Answer (score 0):

`fflush` does not create new file descriptors.

You probably keep re-opening that file but forget to close it.

Comment: yes , I wrote a simple program ,and found fflush did not create new descriptors. But , look at my commentary . After fflush file pointer, It really increase the file descriptors number.

Comment: @ttworkhard: "*My application used multi thread*" so propably another thread just opened another file in between to two checks for the number of file descriptors open you did.